# Tiling of a deficient $7\times7$ chessboard with L trominoes

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

> Prove that a $7\times7$ chessboard with one square removed can always be tiled by $L$ trominoes.

I'm looking for a reasonably simple proof. I was able to prove some specific cases, For instance, when the central square is deleted, the chessboard can be partitioned into four $4\times3$ rectangles, which can be easily tiled.

However, I was unable to prove the general case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's a tromino?

Comment: Use induction for triomino problems.

Comment: @KamalSaleh TRIOmino is another kind of triangle thing. The term TROmino is actually correct. Please refer to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this (i am going draw some formal pictures after I have taken a nap.)

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
X&X&\circ&\circ&\triangle&\triangle&\circ\\
\hline
X&X&\circ&\square&\triangle&\circ&\circ\\
\hline
\circ&\circ&\square&\square&\blacksquare &\blacksquare &\square\\
\hline
\circ&\triangle&\circ&\circ&\blacksquare&\square&\square\\
\hline
\triangle&\triangle&\circ&\square&\square&\triangle&\triangle\\
\hline
\circ&\circ&\triangle&\square&\circ&\triangle&\square\\
\hline
\circ&\triangle&\triangle&\circ&\circ&\square&\square\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\square&\square&\circ&\triangle&\triangle&\circ&\circ\\
\hline
\square&\circ&\circ&\triangle&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\circ\\
\hline
X&X&\square&\square&\blacksquare &\square &\square\\
\hline
X&X&\circ&\square&\triangle&\triangle&\square\\
\hline
\triangle&\triangle&\circ&\circ&\triangle&\circ&\circ\\
\hline
\triangle&\circ&\triangle&\triangle&\square&\circ&\triangle\\
\hline
\circ&\circ&\triangle&\square&\square&\triangle&\triangle\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\square&\square&\circ&\triangle&\triangle&\circ&\circ\\
\hline
\square&\circ&\circ&\triangle&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\circ\\
\hline
\triangle&\triangle&X&X&\blacksquare &\square &\square\\
\hline
\triangle&\square&X&X&\triangle&\triangle&\square\\
\hline
\square&\square&\circ&\circ&\triangle&\circ&\circ\\
\hline
\circ&\circ&\triangle&\circ&\square&\circ&\triangle\\
\hline
\circ&\triangle&\triangle&\square&\square&\triangle&\triangle\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: You can use this if you like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvUJa.png

Comment: Perfect.. how did you arrive at the answers so quickly?

Comment: @Aspirant I don't know but I think I just placed those tiles randomly and then I can tile this completely... it is not hard, I think. It is just like doing puzzles quickly...

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Games/TrominoPuzzleN.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You need only check the yellow cases, as all other cases can be found by a trivial symmetry:

[image]

Comment: You seem to like the word "trivial". I noticed that one finds many occurences of this adjective in your answers. IMHO, with due respect, one should use it more scarcely. Here for example, I don't see how all situations are "trivialy" a consequence of what you say...

Comment: It is trivial to rotate the figure by 90 degrees, 180 degrees or 270 degrees, and to flip left-to-right or up-and-down, thereby covering all component squares in the full grid.  If that isn't "trivial," it is hard to know what would be.